# integrated LED light fixture

Tags: electrical

Will a integrated dimmable light fixture work with a regular switch instead of an dimmable light switch? I installed one and it doesn't work.

Comment: There's no inherent reason it _shouldn't_, so it's possible that you've miswired something. Please provide make/model of the light fixture and switch, as well as clear, focused pics of the wiring inside the box behind the light and behind the switch. You can [edit] those into your original post, and you can hit the "sun & mountain" icon to have them automatically uploaded & hosted by this site and have them show directly in the post. If you can't figure that out, post to Imgur or other pic sharing site, post the links & someone will edit it in for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if it works at all (properly wired, not defective) it should work with a plain switch.

I have a bunch of dimmable LEDs on plain switches - they start about 1/2 second faster; they are slightly brighter (most LED dimmers don't fully bypass and are less than 100% bright as a result); and one of the fixture types I have makes an annoying hum on an LED dimmer, but makes no noise on a switch.

Comment: I also have some LED bulbs (not fixtures) that make an annoying hum unless turned up to full brightness.

Comment: These ones hum at any brightness level - how much is the fixture's fault .vs. the dimmer's fault, I don't know, but it drove me nuts and I said to heck with dimming them once I sorted out that a plain switch made them quiet. Others on the same type of dimmer are quiet.